# Какой класс коллекций использовать чтобы создать только односвязный список?

Tags: java

Есть ли в java класс, который реализует только односвязный список? 
Как распределяется память под односвязный список? 
Элементы распределяются хаотично или находяться в одном блоке? А под ArrayList?

Answer (score 3):

Реализации односвязного списка в коллекциях java нет. Есть коллекция, которая реализована на основе двусвязного списка, это LinkedList. А вот коллекция ArrayList основана на массиве, а под массив память выделяется блоками.
Вы можете написать свою реализацию односвязного списка, в этом случае если создавать новый элемент коллекции через оператор new, то нет никакой гарантии, в каком порядке будут расположены эти объекты в памяти